# GIt keep current version when merging (our version or their)

Tags: git, bitbucket-server, git-fork

I have created a fork with automatic synchronization in BitBucket Server.

I modified one file on the branch on the fork and I want it to remain static, where automatic syncing would just bring changes for anything else that changes and leave static file the way it is.

Is it possible to set something up so it happens automatically without a request for manual merges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to set something up so it happens automatically without a request for manual merges?

Of course

The trick is to use `merge.ours.driver true`

```
# set the desired merge strategy for the given file
git config merge.ours.driver true

# Mark the file you want in .gitattributes
echo 'FILE_NAME merge=ours' >> .gitattributes
```

---

#### **`merge driver`**

a command responsible for the actual merging files.

```
git config --global merge.ours.driver true
```

The above configuration will define a merge driver that would **always favor our current version of the file**.